# Why setenv fails when set works find in tcsh

Tags: shell, eval, tcsh

Following `setenv` works in `tcsh` script but fails weirdly with `eval` in `tcsh`.

I have 2 simple files with the following content

```
> head *.tcsh
==> set.tcsh <==
set intVar = 10
set strVar = a

==> setenv.tcsh <==
setenv intVar 10
setenv strVar a
```

The first file with `set` one works fine with `eval`, but the second file with `setenv` fails with the error `setenv: Too many arguments`

```
> tcsh -c 'eval `cat set.tcsh` ; (set ; printenv) | grep -P "^...Var"'
intVar  10
strVar  a
> tcsh -c 'eval `cat setenv.tcsh` ; (set ; printenv) | grep -P "^...Var"'
setenv: Too many arguments.
```

But both scripts work fine as standalone `tcsh` scripts

```
> echo 'echo $intVar $strVar' >> set.tcsh
> echo 'echo $intVar $strVar' >> setenv.tcsh
> tcsh ./set.tcsh
10 a
> tcsh ./setenv.tcsh
10 a
```

It sounds weird the `eval` has all the issues.

Tcsh version

```
> which eval
eval: shell built-in command.
> tcsh --version
tcsh 6.21.00 (Astron) 2019-05-08 (x86_64-unknown-linux) options wide,nls,dl,al,kan,sm,rh,nd,color,filed
```

Why `eval` is behaving that way, anything alternative to eval that is recommended in `tcsh`?

Comment: Questions of why you're using tcsh aside, why are you using `eval`? What is your ultimate goal you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: The `setenv.tcsh` file will be generated at runtime and script is supposed to use the values of those variables in the script, if you are asking why `tcsh`? well, its one of the scripting languages used in my team

Comment: Hint: `source` is your friend. And @tchrist wrote a [famous essay](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/) almost 20 years ago on some of the problems with (t)csh.

Comment: I know `tcsh` is not that great, this attempt is nearly to support `tcsh` along with other shells for compatibility. We can't use `source` as we do not actually intend to generate the file. One script generates the file's content (i.e., `setenv` lines), and the calling script is supposed to use them. I could not get it working with `source`. Thank you for the article by the way.